# Laravel view rendering issue

Tags: php, laravel, view

Following is my controller class,

```
namespace Admin;
class CategoriesController extends \BaseController {

    public function index($action = '', $id= ''){
       //return \View::make('welcome');View is correctly rendered here
        switch ($action){
            case ''     :
            case 'list' : $this->showList();
            break;
            case 'add'  : $this->addCategories();
            break;
            case 'edit' : $this->editCategories($id);
            break;
        }

    }

    public function showList($id_category =''){
        echo "testing";
        return \View::make('welcome'); //it does not work here
   }
```

While calling the view, it does not work within the function showList(). The echo inside the function works, but the view just return a blank page without any errors. What could be the issue here?

Comment: What does the dd(\View::make('welcome')); show? in laravel 5  I recommend you to use  view() instead.
Probably the issue is because of namespaces as View is Illuminate\Support\Facades\View not \View

Comment: It was printing the view. The mistake was with the return. Thanks for the concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you want to call `showList` from the `index` function and not from the routes. If so, there's no return action from the `index` function. In order to make it work, you need to return within the `index` function what is returned from `showList` function, otherwise, the View will not be rendered. Try changing your `index` function to:

```
public function index($action = '', $id= '') {
    switch ($action) {
        case ''     :
        case 'list' : 
                    return $this->showList();
        case 'add'  : 
                    return $this->addCategories();
        case 'edit' : 
                    return $this->editCategories($id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

here is the problem...remove the / from the return view line

```
public function showList($id_category =''){
    echo "testing";
    return View::make('welcome'); //it does not work here
```

}

Comment: That is used for the namespace and not the reason for the issue. The view is rendered within index function with the same.